# Group by and lag in dplyr

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate a lag of the total flights per day by date in nycflights2013. I followed some examples with group by and just didn't work.

```
df<- nycflights13::flights
df<- df %>% add_count(as.Date(time_hour))
df<- df %>% group_by(n) %>% mutate (lag1= lag(n,order_by = as.Date(time_hour)))
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Using `dplyr`

```r
library(dplyr)

df<- nycflights13::flights

df %>% 
        group_by(year,month,day) %>% 
        summarise(flights = n()) %>% 
        mutate(lag1 = as.numeric(flights - lag(flights))) %>% 
        na.omit()

#> # A tibble: 353 x 5
#> # Groups:   year, month [12]
#>     year month   day flights  lag1
#>    <int> <int> <int>   <int> <dbl>
#>  1  2013     1     2     943   101
#>  2  2013     1     3     914   -29
#>  3  2013     1     4     915     1
#>  4  2013     1     5     720  -195
#>  5  2013     1     6     832   112
#>  6  2013     1     7     933   101
#>  7  2013     1     8     899   -34
#>  8  2013     1     9     902     3
#>  9  2013     1    10     932    30
#> 10  2013     1    11     930    -2
#> # … with 343 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Or this?

```r
library(dplyr)

df<- nycflights13::flights

df %>% 
        group_by(time_hour) %>% 
        summarise(flights = n()) %>% 
        mutate(lag1 = as.numeric(flights - lag(flights))) %>% 
        na.omit()

#> # A tibble: 6,935 x 3
#>    time_hour           flights  lag1
#>    <dttm>                <int> <dbl>
#>  1 2013-01-01 06:00:00      52    46
#>  2 2013-01-01 07:00:00      49    -3
#>  3 2013-01-01 08:00:00      58     9
#>  4 2013-01-01 09:00:00      56    -2
#>  5 2013-01-01 10:00:00      39   -17
#>  6 2013-01-01 11:00:00      37    -2
#>  7 2013-01-01 12:00:00      56    19
#>  8 2013-01-01 13:00:00      54    -2
#>  9 2013-01-01 14:00:00      48    -6
#> 10 2013-01-01 15:00:00      67    19
#> # … with 6,925 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>